# Configure Intellij Idea to import generated files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, configuration

I'm having trouble to import a generated package with Intellij, however without any changes to the default settings it works on Eclipse.

Here is my architechture:

```
├── build.properties
├── pom.xml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │       └── mypackage
│   └── test
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── mypackage
    |       └── generated
    ├── generated-sources
    ├── generated-test-sources
    ├── APP.jar
    └── test-classes
```

I have most of my classes in com.mypackage however some of them are generated in

```
└── target
    ├── classes
        └── mypackage
```

named as `com.mypackage.generated` and i have to use these classes in `com.mypackage`:

```
├── src
    ├── main
        ├── java
            └── mypackage
```

However intellij cannot resolve symbol `generated` when I'm doing
`import com.mypackage.generated`

I tried to make it work by looking at the `project structure/modules/dependencies` menu but it seems to be for external modules. How can I do this ?

Comment: You have to enter in Project Structure and mark as Sources the "generated" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was very simple, I only was about marking `classes` as sources root. I don't know why marking `generated` as sources root did not work.